# Why am I required to call setBounds twice for it to work

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel, setbounds

As part of an application I'm writing, I resize and move a picture of a pallet in a `JLabel`. Because the `JLabel` is in a `JLayeredPane`, I'm not using a layout manager, and as a result, ever time I resize the palletLabel's icon I use `setBounds()` to control its dimensions and location on the page. A picture of what it looks like is below:

[image]

The code that controls what happens when the pallet is image is resized is called each time the dimensions (specified by the `JSpinners` that can be seen to the left) are changed. The `palletLabel` is resized is below:

```
private void resizePalletImage(int[] size)
{
    Dimension dim = calculatePalletImageSize(size[1], size[0]);
    palletImage = ResizeImage.scaleImageByAbsoluteValues(originalPalletImage, dim);
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(palletImage);
    palletLabel.setIcon(icon);
    layerPanelHeight = layerCenterPanel.getHeight();
    //Have to set this twice, as the length hasn't "updated" by the time the first setBounds is called. Weird.
    palletLabel.setBounds(0, layerPanelHeight - palletLabel.getHeight(), icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight());
    palletLabel.setBounds(0, layerPanelHeight - palletLabel.getHeight(), icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight());
}
```

- `originalPalletImage` is a high resolution copy of the original image, this is used to prevent blurring after lots of image resizing.
- `ResizeImage.scaleImageByAbsoluteValues` is a static method that is used to resize the image. It just calls `Image.getScaledInstance` after a couple of calculations.
- `layerCenterPanel` is the `JLayeredPane` upon which `panelLabel` sits.

As seen, I call `setBounds()` twice at the end. Initially it was only called once, and it resized the `palletLabel`, but it didn't use the values that had just been set earlier in the method, but rather the previous values, and the pallet image floated about where it shouldnt (as the previous value for `palletLabel.getHeight()` was being used). In other words, the method worked as intended but was always one iteration behind. I have solved this by just calling `setBounds()` twice and it now works exactly as intended. I am simply wondering why this is necessary, I tried putting `setBounds()` within an `invokeLater` but it had no effect.

Any input is welcome,
Thanks.

Comment: maybe you forgot to call a (re)paint

Comment: just tried 1 `setBounds()` followed by a `repaint()`, and it still exhibits the 'delayed' setting